# Why is my @results Quiz object nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I pass the following to the `results/index.html.erb` view:

```
 def create
        @results = Quiz.where(user_id: current_user.id)
            redirect_to results_path
    end
```

(I've changed the above action BACK to create).

Then, in my `results/index.html.erb` view:

```
<div class="container">
      <!-- Example row of columns -->
      <div class="row">
        <h1>Results page</h1>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <p>Eventually a user's results will appear here...</p>
          <p><%= @results %></p>
          <p><%= @results.inspect %></p>
          <p><%= current_user.quiz %></p>
             <h4>Quiz Answer</h4>
             <p><%= @results.answer1 %></p>
             <p><%= @results.answer2 %></p>
             <p><%= @results.answer3 %></p>
             <p><%= @results.answer4 %></p>
             <p><%= @results.answer5 %></p>
             <p><%= @results.answer6 %></p>
             <p><%= @results.answer7 %></p>
             <p><%= @results.answer8 %></p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <footer>
        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="showmetheskills.html" role="button">next</a></p>
      </footer>
    </div> <!-- /container -->
```

(I know it's not 'best practise' to have numbered attributes on a Model; ignore that part.)

I get the error:

```
undefined method 'answer1' for nil:NilClass
```

Why is `@results` nil, when I set it IN THE ACTION Rails is asking for?

The `Quiz` is created in the `QuizzesController`:

```
def new
    @user = current_user
    @quiz = Quiz.create(user_id: current_user.id)
end
```

Which triggers `quizzes/new.html.erb` which renders the quiz partial.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

`@results` is nil because you've done a redirect. Either render the view

```
def update
  @results = Quiz.where(user_id: current_user.id)
  render: 'results#index'
end
```

Or do the redirect and get the results there which would be my preferred option, but I'd question why you're sending them to the update action without updating anything.

```
def update
  redirect_to results_path
end

def ResultsController
  def index
    @results = Quiz.where(user_id: current_user.id)
  end
end
```

Either way things like `@results.answer1` won't work because you have an active record relation.  You either need to loop

```
<% @results.each do |result| %>
  <%= result.answer1 %>
<% end %>
```

Or grab the first result

`@results = Quiz.where(user_id: current_user.id).first`

Answer (score 0):

In your case `@results` is an array and you call some `answer1, answer2, answer3...` methods(that are not defined yet I guess) on array that also does not exists.

Next:

You initialize `@results` in update action, but expect it to work in `resuzlts/index.html.erb`.

To show `@results` in index html you need to load this variable in `index` action.

**Update**

If you want your `index` action to show something, put this line:

```
@results = Quiz.where(user_id: current_user.id)
```

into index action

```
def index
  # here
end
```

and remove `answer1, answer2, answer3....` from `index.html.erb`, they really makes no sense.
Also, `index.html.erb` should look like this:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <p><%= current_user.quiz %></p>
  <h4>Quiz Answer</h4>

  <% @results.each do |result| %>
    <p><%= result.answer %></p>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

this would work only if you have `answer` defined for result. Hard to say what is what in your app.

Comment: Can I ask how you know @results in an Array?

Comment: Because you call `.where` on a class that will return an array of objects that meet your conditions(user_id = current_user.id). Start with this man http://learnrubythehardway.org/book/